# Best method to show blur images in an Android app

Tags: android, performance

I want to set blur image for an activity (something like Spotify mobile).

Images are recieved from internet.

What method have best performance for first time? (because we cache blurred images in memory for next uses)

1. Use realtime blurring with Java and an Bitmap blur library (StackBlur)
2. Blur images with Photoshop or another tool and store them into internet then do a http get request to load in app

Comment: Do some tests. Both methods require some processing (image processing vs dowloading).

Comment: @DerGolem I need to know what methods has less processing; does anybody has already done a test?

Comment: Aren't you able to do the tests yourself?